# How to connect Gitlab and on-premise Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, minikube

I have a Kubernetes cluster running on my laptop and I want to connect it to Gitlab so that I can deploy my application to Kubernetes from Gitlab pipelines. 
I was reading the official documentation but could not find anything useful.

Can anyone shade some light on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a pod in your local Kubernetes as a Gitlab Runner. More information (setup a runner) [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html), [here](https://github.com/teacheraio/DevSecOps-Studio/wiki/Lesson-one:-Setting-up-Git-Server-and-Gitlab-CI-Runner.), and (Kubernetes Runner) [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html)

Note that it should work if you have egress traffic allowed  In most cases, egress is allowed unless your environment is following some sort of compliance. (ie. PCI, SOX, etc)

Comment: can you explain how this is going to work, how seting up a pod in my local Kubernetes as a Gitlab Runner going to help me my issue. Will this also works with on-premise clusters. ?

Comment: @rajan.sngh this it should work if you have egress traffic allowed on your on-premise cluster. In most cases, egress is allowed unless your on-premise environment is following some sort of compliance.

Comment: by running a pod i am able to connect. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Rico, Why do we need to set up a Pod as Runner in K8s ? why can't we set up a runner on a machine(ubuntu, centos) and point it our cluster. As per you answer, my set up is up and running and but i am not able to provide a suitable answer to question- why do we need a runner as a Pos.

Comment: You don't need a runner as a pod, that's an option (which is the links that I mentioned). But in reality, you can have runners anywhere standalone or as pods.